# Kint works in pre_process but not in Twig

Tags: 8, theming

On my site, I'm able to use print variables using kint in my pre-process functions.

However, when I try to do the same in twig, nothing happens.  I do have debug mode turned on.  Has anyone ever ran into this fact pattern? Any ideas?

**To clarify:**

- It does not work in any of my templates
- The specific template I'm using is for styling the output of a view, which is a page and has unformatted HTML as its type.

This is how I use kint  `kint()`

This is what I have seen on tutorials.

Comment: Without seeing how you actually use is, we can't say what's wrong. Please update your question to include code snippets of what you are trying to do and WHERE. What file? What template? What code?

Comment: Just to make sure that you know, you do like this to kint in twig, `{{ kint(variable) }}`

Comment: Jdrupal, I will be happy to let you know once I test. I have had to work on other things and have not yet tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you use kint like this, `kint($variable)`, but in twig you use kint like this, `{{ kint(variable) }}`.

This is the only problem I can spot by looking at your question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In PHP I'd recommend `ksm($variable)` which will print the output into the Status messages block (in D7 this was `dpm($variable)`).

Comment: When I try to "kint" the "item" variable in a loop, I get a white screen.